# htaccess rewriteRule in localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a project in `taha` directory of my localhost, the client side part is in `FrontEnd` directory , now:

How can I rewrite `localhost/taha/FrontEnd` to `localhost` in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^taha/FrontEnd/ taha/FrontEnd%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: For JS/CSS you can use: `<base href="/taha/FrontEnd">` in your page's `<head>` section.